# Surround numbers with a frame

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've seen answers about how to surround numbers with a circle, but my request is to put a irregular frame. Like this (Geogebra):[image]

In those answers, I found that the function of drawing the circle is provided by tikz directly, so I don't know how to make a shape that tikz does not provide.

It would be fine to use tikz or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n) {13};
\draw let \p1=(n.east), \p2=(n.center), \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in (\p1) arc[radius=\n1, start angle=0, end angle=270] -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The number 13 in a shape]

**Edit:** Aligned to baseline

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\framed}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\node[anchor=base] (n) {#1};
\draw let \p1=(n.east), \p2=(n.center), \n1={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in (\p1) arc[radius=\n1, start angle=0, end angle=270] -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
Normal $13$ and framed \framed{$13$}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text with number 13 in irregular frame]

Comment: How could I make the picture a bit lower so that the number aligns horizontally with other text?